# Monit syntax error When reading shell script in /etc/monit.d/

Tags: bash, shell, monit

Attempting to run a PHP script via shell script and keep getting a 'syntax error' from Monit when reading the shell script.

launchQueue.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
php /var/app/current/hello.php
```

The shell script will run on it's own and I've opened up all permissions. Monit is calling it from it's own directory /etc/monit.d/* - which is supposed to run all files within it when monit starts up.

Exact error reads: "/etc/monit.d/launchQueue.sh:2: Error: syntax error 'php'"

- I have moved it out of monit.d as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101842/monit-errors-when-running-check-program-for-custom-script) suggests, but I get the same error.

Running Monit Versions 5.2.5

Comment: You're missing the `!` in `#!/bin/sh`, for starters.

Comment: I had "!" in there, it was a type when inserting it on stack.

Comment: Your error refers to `launchQueue.sh`, but your example shows `launchHello.sh`.  Are the contents you're showing here identical to the file that is causing this error? Are you certain there's not a hidden carriage return (`\r`) at the end of the previous line (you can check with `od -a <filename>` and look for "cr" in the output)?

Comment: Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101842/monit-errors-when-running-check-program-for-custom-script

Comment: Ya, sorry. launchQueue = launchHello - It's been a long day. This has taken up the majority of it... That stack question you mention was the one I was referring to when I said, i had already taken the sh script out of monit.d.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Hadn't followed that link yet.

Comment: No worries, I'm going with SupervisorD instead of Monit. Monit just isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Monit is having it own *PATH* and it is very small *PATH*. You should provide the full path to you *php* executable or re-defined the PATH in your script.

Try with (tune according to your location)

`#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/php /var/app/current/hello.php`

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I think I figured it out (in answers).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was and it was largely due to my own ignorance of using the terminal (I'm pretty new). I installed SupervisorD and ran into similar issues. It turned out that my root $PATH didn't include the normal user (?) $PATH. Once I exported the PATH over to root, it ran just fine.